# Comma after Yeah

Tags: punctuation, commas

Yeah, but it seems like I will reach by 12.00 pm. Is it grammatically correct, is comma is required after "Yeah". When should someone use comma. If possible provide examples.

Comment: Is it clear to your audience what you will reach? Even if it is, if you are writing for school you may lose credit, because the sentence on its own is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do pause before you say what you're saying "yeah" to.

Uh-huh, I think you should still use the comma.

Really, many people would say that you don't need a comma when "everyone" already knows the pause goes with the word. It's being left out a lot, by publishers, with "too as in also", too.

Personally, I would go with this rule: "If you say the comma, write the comma." Then people know how you are using the word without having to read the next few words, or even the next couple of clauses, then having to go back and re-read from the beginning of your sentence.